Transpose function in excel doesn't work to fit every 4 rows into a new row
I have a txt file which has only 1 column and many rows. I wanted to create a table from that txt file using the function transpose in excel to conver the rows into columns. However, my data has the same data type every 4 rows (example in green and white columns) and when I use the transpose function on excel, it transpose every raw into a new colum but I wanted to make in the new table, a new row, every 4 rows, which is the "begining" of the row.
I will leave a diagram with the desired result on the right.
| Column A |           Cell1| Cell2 | Cell 3
| -------- |           Cell1.1 | Cell 2.1 | Cell 3.1
| Cell 1   | 
| Cell 2   |      ->    
| Cell 3   | 
| Cell 1.1   | 
| Cell 2.1   |
| Cell 3.1   | 

I tried to make a dynamic table to see if it can fit the content but I didn't get any good result

If you could do this in 365, it would be simple:  =WRAPROWS(A1:A6,3)

This has a solution using MS365 as well as Power Query here. While Excel 2010 --> =IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,COLUMNS($A1:A1)+(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)*3),"")
